# Open Default Mail Client with prefilled attachment - Web (Asp.Net MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, email, email-attachments

after searching couple hours I realized that such easy task (or at least it seemd like that) is not that easy to achive.

So,is there a possiblity to open a prefilled  mail client window from a web application (with prefilled I mean with an added attachment)? I am using ASP.NET Mvc, but I guess thats not that important bcz the code needs to be executed on the client.

I tried with mailto and &attachment="C:\file.txt" but this doenst work.I read that it may not be possible bcz of security reasons. That doenst make sense to me at all, bcz the point is that the user can see the mail before he sends it (so its more secure than automatically sending a mail).

And I dont want a server side sending, bcz that way every user needs to provide their credentials, and besides that, maybe the user wants to change smt inside the mail before he sends it.

This is about a corporate software, and when the user clicks on a link, I create a document on the server, download it to the client, and well, for now, try to attach it to a mail, and open the freshly created mail

Thanks 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Though you said:

> the code needs to be executed on the client

given the requirements you posted, it is still possible and valid to do it on the server. If there are other reasons why you shouldn't do it on the server, please tell me.

---

If you have access to the attachment file on the server, you could generate a `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` object on your server, add the attachment, and pass the file via download to the user. (A little bit tricky but see below for possible solution)

Only downside of this is, that the user has to actively open the downloaded mail file, instead of the mail program opening instantly.

This is how you could convert the MailMessage to a byte-array (assuming you are using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)):

```
public static byte[] ToEml(this MailMessage message)
{
    var assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
    var mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
        var mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);

        // Construct MailWriter object with our FileStream
        var mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { memoryStream });

        // Get reflection info for Send() method on MailMessage
        var sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Call method passing in MailWriter
        sendMethod.Invoke(message, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);

        // Finally get reflection info for Close() method on our MailWriter
        var closeMethod = mailWriter.GetType().GetMethod("Close", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        // Call close method
        closeMethod.Invoke(mailWriter, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new object[] { }, null);

        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

(Found [here](http://metdepuntnaarvoren.nl/create-eml-file-from-system.netmail.mailmessage))

And afterwards build a controller action that returns this byte-array as a file result:

```
var result =
    new FileContentResult(messageBytes, "application/vnd.ms-outlook")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "WhateverDownloadNameYouNeed.eml"
    };
```

You have to change the contenttype in case you're not using Outlook.

Comment: Clicking on the downloaded file to open it, hmm... Lets, for the moment, say I could live with that, whats with mobile phones ? What if I want to use my web application on an iPhone, Android ? MailTo works fine on the devices, but there is no Outlook ...

Comment: Unfortunately i do not see any possibility to achieve that with my solution. You could of course change the content type which is currently set to outlook, to a different one depending on your device. But sadly i'm not that experienced in that area, and have no idea how a mobile device will handle that file and if there's any possibility to open an .eml file with the google mail app for example.